Echo Framework rendering html from muliple directory's
im using the web framework from echo labs
I'm trying to render html and css from different folders in my project
type TemplateRenderer struct {
    templates *template.Template
}

// Render renders a template document
func (t *TemplateRenderer) Render(w io.Writer, name string, data interface{}, c echo.Context) error {

    // Add global methods if data is a map
    if viewContext, isMap := data.(map[string]interface{}); isMap {
        viewContext["reverse"] = c.Echo().Reverse
    }

    return t.templates.ExecuteTemplate(w, name, data)
}

    renderer := &TemplateRenderer{
        templates: template.Must(template.ParseGlob("htmlfolder1/*.html")),
    }


im using the web framework
so i want to have lots of folders each with they own html and css
the abve code work for one folder but im i cant find anything in the docs to let me use more than one folder .
